# NullPointerException on ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I already populated a database by XML parsing and I'm having a hard time making it output in a listview. Can someone help me know why my listview isn't working? Thanks.

UserWorkout.java

```
package com.example.istronggyminstructor;

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
public class UserWorkout extends Activity {
    PopupWindow popup;
    View popupview;
    Button addworkoutbut;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String userselected = i.getExtras().getString("userselect");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_workout);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputuser);
        tv1.setText(userselected);
        addworkoutbut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addworkoutbut);

    }


    public void onClickAddWorkout(View v){
        v = new View
                (this);
        dataHandler dbHandler = new dataHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        //xmlparser();

        addworkoutbut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addworkoutbut);
        final LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        popupview = inflator.inflate(R.layout.popup4, null);
        popup = new PopupWindow(popupview,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popup.showAtLocation(popupview, Gravity.CENTER, 0, -10);
        popup.setFocusable(true);
        popup.update();


        List<String> user = dbHandler.getAllWorkouts();
        //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                //android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2, user);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, user));
        final ListView lv = (ListView)popupview.findViewById(R.id.workoutlists);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        Button cancelbtn = (Button) popupview.findViewById(R.id.closepopup4);
        cancelbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                popup.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }


    }
```

activity_user_workout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.istronggyminstructor.UserWorkout" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addworkoutbut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="onClickAddWorkout"
        android:text="@string/addworkout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/workouthistory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addworkoutbut"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:text="@string/workouthistory"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outputuser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addworkoutbut"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/workouthistory"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/workouthistory"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/addworkoutbut"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/workouthistory"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/workoutname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#dcdcdc"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dip"
                android:text="col1"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalscore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#dcdcdc"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dip"
                android:text="col2"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/datein"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#dcdcdc"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dip"
                android:text="col3"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeincol2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#dcdcdc"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dip"
                android:text="col4"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

LOGCAT:

```
05-25 03:40:47.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3406): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 03:40:47.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3406): Process: com.example.istronggyminstructor, PID: 3406
05-25 03:40:47.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3406): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 03:40:47.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3406):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
05-25 03:40:47.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3406):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
05-25 03:40:47.540: E/AndroidRuntime(3406):     at
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing your own `ArrayAdapter`, then check your `getItem()` implementation to make sure you are not returning null.

If not, check the values you are passing into your ArrayAdapter, it appears one of them is null and is causing the `ArrayAdapter` to blow up.